# Pl/SQL web application

Tags: oracle, plsql, web-server

I have a PL/SQL web application,got the entire DB dump from remote DB.
Its very old application, running on oracle 9i.
I basically want to get the application up and running on my laptop,but i am not able to figure out how.
Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: How does this application expect to interact with the web server? Does it use the OWA standard? If so, https://oss.oracle.com/projects/mod_owa/dist/documentation/modowa.htm might be the easiest way to get this up and running.

Comment: yes, it does use OWA.

Comment: I used fiddler to see the request/response, found that the application is running on Oracle HTTP Server (OHS) powered by apache 1.3.2, mod_plsql , mod_ssl, openssll,mod_fastcgi,mod_oprocmgr.Can you please let me know how to configure OHS for pl/sql web application.?

Comment: Google will tell you. http://google.com/search?q=mod_plsql But in my experience the combination of a standard Apache build + mod_owa is much simpler to install and get running -- provided your application doesn't use any esoteric OWA features.

Comment: I understand that mod_owa would be simpler, but i am expected to reverse engineer the Live/production environment and set up the as-is in my local setup.
Also went through couple of links on on mod_plsql,but could not get a accurate link.I have installed OHS, looking out how to configure mod_plsql and get my application up and running.

Comment: If you're copying an existing environment, why don't you copy that environment's settings?

Comment: The situation here is bit complicated.
The application is running from 10 years, no body knows on what infra(s/w) its running,there is no documentation about design,API,architecture or Installation guide.The support group knows how to start and shutdown the application.
Basically, i have to look at the existing application and write all the above documents and focus on improving the problems with existing application.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO the easiest way to get an OWA application to work is by installing a standard Apache distribution and the open source mod_owa.

This is easiest on modern 64bit Windows, downloading Apache 2.4 from http://www.apachelounge.com/download/ and mod_owa from https://oss.oracle.com/projects/mod_owa/dist/documentation/modowa.htm